# Why is my $.post() not working while $.ajax() does?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm building a pretty straightforward function that sends an integer to the server via AJAX. I used to do it this way all the time but suddenly I've run into a problem with the jQuery.post method.

The following does not work:

```
jQuery.post({
    dataType : 'json',
    url : server_vars.ajax_url,
    data : {
        action : 'toggle_book',
        _ajax_nonce : server_vars.nonce,
        book_id : book_id
    },
    success : function( response ) {
        if( response.success ) {
            alert('done');
        }
        else {
            alert('error');
        }
    }
});
```

I get the following 404 error:

> POST [http://example.com/[object%20Object]](http://example.com/%5Bobject%20Object%5D)

However, if I switch the code to the following, it works:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    method : 'post',
    dataType : 'json',
    url : server_vars.ajax_url,
    data : {
        action : 'toggle_book',
        _ajax_nonce : server_vars.nonce,
        book_id : book_id
    },
    success : function( response ) {
        if( response.success ) {
            alert('done');
        }
        else {
            alert('error');
        }
    }
});
```

There is nothing wrong with my server_vars variable, it's just a json object that I can access anywhere else (including with the "fixed" code above). I googled to see if the post method was deprecated and it doesn't seem to be the case.

I've done this a million times and all of a sudden it started giving me this issue which I find baffling.

This is running on WordPress 5.5

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of jQuery? prior to 1.12 that signature for $.post didn't exist.

Comment: Unable to replicate: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/zg52awm1/. If you check the network tab of the console you'll see that the `data` is encoded in to the body of request as it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `[object%20Object]` in the url you posted, it looks like it tries to convert the object to a string.

This might mean that you are using a jQuery version before 1.12, which did not support to only pass an options object.

If you see the signature of the [`jQuery.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) (*for up to v1.12*) you will see that the url is the first parameter and does not go in the options object.

```
jQuery.post(server_vars.ajax_url, {
    dataType : 'json',
    data : {
        action : 'toggle_book',
        _ajax_nonce : server_vars.nonce,
        book_id : book_id
    },
    success : function( response ) {
        if( response.success ) {
            alert('done');
        }
        else {
            alert('error');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan oups

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah, no worries. Updated answer as well.

Comment: I must be going crazy, I could have sworn that I've been doing it this way for years.

Comment: @Gazillion, it could be your other website were using a more modern version of jQuery. 1.0 is **very** old. The v1.12 which supports your original syntax was released in 2016.